# Why does react compute render twice before initial load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was under the impression that react render computes once and compares it with DOM to make the change?

However, from my simple **example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-rain-ej8fu?file=/src/App.js it seems even before the component mounts. The render function is exceuted twice. I've also included a screenshot below to clarify my point. In the console you can see `console.log(value)` is evaluated twice. I wonder what conceptual mistake I'm making here!

**Code:**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Load() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("intial Value");

  console.log(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("mounted");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{value}</h1>
      <button onClick={e => setValue(Math.random())}>Update state</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Load;
```

**Screenshot:**
[react initial reload error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4L7k.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because codesandbox uses React Strict Mode. React Strict Mode is for better debugging, so, after rendering it reruns all the lifecycle methods to make sure they're "safe". You can reead more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html). So, just remove React.StrictMode tag in index.js file.

Comment: Thank you! :) This solves my problem. Marked as accepted.

Comment: Glad I could help.